# Pythonic way to search a list using keywords

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am attempting to search for text between two keywords. My solution so far is using `split()` to change string to list. It works but I was wondering if there is more efficient/elegant way to achieve this. Below is my code:

```
words = "Your meeting with Dr Green at 8pm"
list_words = words.split()
before = "with"
after = "at"
title = list_words[list_words.index(before) + 1]
name = list_words[list_words.index(after) - 1]


if title != name:
    var = title + " " + name
    print(var)
else:
    print(title)
```

Results:

```
>>> Dr Green
```

Id prefer a solution that is configurable as the text I'm searching for can be dynamic so Dr Green could be replaced by a name with 4 words or 1 word.

Comment: Why not get the index of "with" and "at" and then just extract whatever is between those words as your parsing object to extract name, surname, title etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a job for regular expressions. This uses the pattern `(?:with)(.*?)(?:at)` to look for 'with', and 'at', and lazily match anything in-between.

```
import re

words = 'Your meeting with Dr Green at 8pm'
start = 'with'
end = 'at'

pattern = r'(?:{})(.*?)(?:{})'.format(start, end)
match = re.search(pattern, words).group(1).strip()
print(match)
```

---

Outputs;

```
Dr Green
```

Note that the Regex does actually match the spaces on either side of `Dr Green`, I've included a simple `match.strip()` to remove trailing whitespace.

Comment: Maybe add a `strip()` call at the end to get rid of the whitespace.

Comment: @mwchase thanks - I had noticed that it includes the spaces, I assume that's what OP wants given that that does in fact match what's between the two characters, but I'll make a clarification anyway.

Comment: @ Tom Wyllie Thanks - Desired output would have no spaces on either side but a space between title and name.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, I've updated my answer to show that behaviour 'by default' now.

Comment: You can handle white spaces in the assertions with: `r'(?:{}\s*)(.*?)(?:\s*{})'`. No need to `strip` later.

Comment: I agree @MosesKoledoye - but I felt that that would make my answer too specific to OP's exact use case, and less appropriate for the general problem of searching for text between two keywords. Good suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Using RE

```
import re
words = "Your meeting with Dr Green at 8pm"
before = "Dr"
after = "at"
result = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (before, after), words).group(1)
print before + result
```

Output :

```
Dr Green
```

Answer (score 0):

How about slicing the list at start and end, then just splitting it?

```
words = "Your meeting with Dr Jebediah Caruseum Green at 8pm"
start = "with"
end = "at"    
list_of_stuff = words[words.index(start):words.index(end)].replace(start, '', 1).split()
list_of_stuff 
['Dr', 'Jebediah', 'Caruseum', 'Green']
```

You can do anything you like with the list. For example I would parse for title like this:

```
list_of_titles = ['Dr', 'Sr', 'GrandMaster', 'Pleb']
try:
    title = [i for i in list_of_stuff if i in list_of_titles][0]
except IndexError:
    #title not found, skipping
    title = ''
name = ' '.join([x for x in list_of_stuff if x != title])
print(title, name)
```

Comment: @ BobDarph - Thanks, interesting alternative to regex but the output format is incorrect. Perhaps I'd have to concatenate the list to have string output?

Comment: Added some details about parsing the resulting list, finding the name, title etc.